# How to convert to title case a specific column

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have come up with this code:

```
cut -d';' -f4 columns.csv | sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g'
```

which actually does the job for the fourth column, but in the way I have lost the other columns..

I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
cut -d';' -f4 columns.csv | sed -i 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g'
```

So, how could I apply the change to that specific column in the file and keep other columns as they are?

Let say that columns.csv content is:

```
TEXT;more text;SoMe MoRe TeXt;THE FOURTH COLUMN;something else
```

Then, expected output should be:

```
TEXT;more text;SoMe MoRe TeXt;The Fourth Column;something else
```

Comment: Can there be other charaters aside letters, digits and spaces in the columns?

Comment: Yes, dashes, parenthesis and dots: ( - . )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU sed:

```
sed -ri 's/;/&\r/3;:1;s/\r([^; ]+\s*)/\L\u\1\r/;t1;s/\r//' columns.csv
```

update:

```
sed -i 's/; */&\n/3;:1;s/\n\([^; ]\+ *\)/\L\u\1\n/;t1;s/\n//' columns.csv
```

Place anchor `\r` (`\n`) at the beginning of field 4. We edit the whole word and move the anchor to the beginning of the next one. Jump by label `t1` `:1` is carried out as long as there are matches for the pattern in the `substitution` command. Removing the anchor.

Comment: Even better, with previous perl script I was having some issues with non ascii characters like À, Ç, etc, this sed command solved that... Thanks to you also, and the others for this great help!!!

Comment: We don't know that the input cannot contain `\r`s so it's not a good choice of a character to add as an anchor. You should use `\n` instead since it can't be present in the input as sed is reading the file one `\n`-separated string at a time. You should mention that requires GNU sed for `-r` and `\s` (and maybe other things?).

Comment: @EdMorton, instead of `\r`  there is a choice of `\a` and `\f`, never thought about `\n`, thanks

Comment: The file could contain `\a` and `\f` too so `\n` really is the best choice.

Comment: Why not refer to the fourth field explicitly i.e. `s/[^;]*/\n&/4`

Comment: @potong, this is undoubtedly the best option. But in the second example, it is possible to start the field with a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Not a short simple `awk`, but should work:

```
awk -F";" '{t=split($4,a," ");$4="";for(i=1;i<=t;i++) {a[i]=substr(a[i],1,1) tolower(substr(a[i],2));$4=$4 sprintf("%s ",a[i])}$4=substr($4,1,length($4)-1)}1' OFS=";" file
TEXT;more text;SoMe MoRe TeXt;The Fourth Column;something else
```

Some shorter version

```
awk -F";" '{t=split($4,a," ");$4="";for(i=1;i<=t;i++) {a[i]=substr(a[i],1,1) tolower(substr(a[i],2));$4=$4 a[i](t==i?"":" ")}}1' OFS=";" file
```

Comment: Thanks, nice of you!!

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```sh
$ perl -F';' -lane '$F[3] =~ s/[a-z]+/\L\u$&/gi; print join ";", @F' columns.csv
TEXT;more text;SoMe MoRe TeXt;The Fourth Column;something else
```

- `-F';'` use `;` to split the input line
- `$F[3] =~ s/[a-z]+/\L\u$&/gi` change case only for the 4th column
- `print join ";", @F` print the modified fields

Unicode version:

```sh
perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -F';' -lane '$F[3]=~s/\p{L}+/\L\u$&/gi;
                                       print join ";", @F'
```

Comment: Thanks, actually adding `-i` to this perl command I could do the change in place. Excelent!!

Comment: @AndrésChandía I've added unicode version too, see if that helps

Comment: Thanks, it does help!!

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
{
    title = ""
    numWords = split($4,words,/ /)
    for (wordNr=1; wordNr<=numWords; wordNr++) {
        word = words[wordNr]
        word = toupper(substr(word,1,1)) tolower(substr(word,2))
        title = (wordNr>1 ? title " " : "") word
    }
    $4 = title
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
TEXT;more text;SoMe MoRe TeXt;The Fourth Column;something else
```

True capitalization in a title is much more complicated than that though.

Comment: Nearly an exact copy of my post :)

Comment: @Jotne yeah when I saw yours I thought about not posting this but there were enough things I didn't like in yours (e.g. adding a blank after every word and then removing it at the end rather than just not adding a blank after the final word, modifying $4 on every iteration of the loop, setting FS and OFS to the same value in 2 different places, multiple single letter variables) and it didn't create a mid-point `word` variable for enhancement to fuller title-conversion (e.g. not converting "A" or "of" unless at start of line) if desired that I thought it was worth posting mine too.

Comment: @Jotne my SOP when looking at a question is to try to answer it first and THEN read any existing answers and if there's one close enough to or better than what I came up with then I don't post mine. In this case I could've gone either way about posting mine given  the similarity to yours but decided to do it for the reasons I just mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/[^;]*/\n&\n/4;h;s/\S*/\L\u&/g;H;g;s/\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/' file
```

Delimit the fourth field by newlines and make a copy.

Uppercase the first character of each word.

Append the amended line to the original.

Using pattern matching, replace the original fourth field by the amended one.